# How to hide an external program's windows programmatically?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to hide an external application, ie. not the current application. I want to give the title of the application and it will be hidden. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general terms, you could call [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) to get the HWND of the window in question, then [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx) with `SW_HIDE` to hide the window.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a handle to the window (which you can do using [FindWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx)). Then you need to call [ShowWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx) and set it's shown state to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
ShowWindow(FindWindow(NULL, "WINDOW TITLE"), SW_HIDE);
```